# convert json value to datatable missing some value

Tags: c#, json, datatable

I want to convert the json value to datatable but when i convert to datatable it is missing the id value to convert in datatable.

Json

```
 {
  "territories": {
    "a10b4b1e-8400-4613-8c90-5d282de6a8a6": {
      "id": "a10b4b1e-8400-4613-8c90-5d282de6a8a6",
      "name": "Connecticut",
      "center": [
        41603071,
        -73087651
      ],
      "timeZoneCode": "America/New_York",
      "languageCode": null
    },
    "dc3d9d82-611e-41ba-a6f6-2c33ac5eebd1": {
      "id": "dc3d9d82-611e-41ba-a6f6-2c33ac5eebd1",
      "name": "Orlando",
      "center": [
        28538321,
        -81379242
      ],
      "timeZoneCode": "America/New_York",
      "languageCode": null
    }

  }
}
```

code for convert the json to datatable

```
   private void ConvertJsonToDataTable( string jasonstring)
        {
            try
            {
                string jsonString = jasonstring;

                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(jsonString))
                {
                    dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
                    var sOffers = dynObj.territories;
                  //  var sCoupons = dynObj.coupons;

                    DataTable dtPromotions = new DataTable();
                    dtPromotions.Columns.Add("id", typeof(string));
                    dtPromotions.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
                    dtPromotions.Columns.Add("timeZoneCode", typeof(string));
                    dtPromotions.Columns.Add("languageCode", typeof(string));

                    foreach (var cou in sOffers)
                    {
                        string cou1 = Convert.ToString(cou);
                        string[] RowData = Regex.Split(cou1.Replace("{", "").Replace("}", ""), ",");
                        DataRow nr = dtPromotions.NewRow();
                        foreach (string rowData in RowData)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                int idx = rowData.IndexOf(":");
                                string RowColumns = rowData.Substring(0, idx - 1).Replace("\"", "").Trim();
                                string RowDataString = rowData.Substring(idx + 1).Replace("\"", "");
                                nr[RowColumns] = RowDataString;
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                        dtPromotions.Rows.Add(nr);
                    }

}
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR",MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
```

Comment: a10b4b1e-8400-4613-8c90-5d282de6a8a6 is this stable or it come everytime different value for different terrotries

Comment: @Abhishek it everytime different value for different Territroy

Comment: I belive your code will be much more readable if you will parse territiories into some Territory classes and then (if you'll need) you can map those values to datatable

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy you want that i use this approach `List <Territories > tr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Territories>>(ter);`

Comment: @A.Goutam exactly. And after that `foreach(var territory in tr)` you can add data rows without replacing braces and other json stuff

Answer (score 0):

You should Just replace the line:

```
string cou1 = Convert.ToString(cou);
```

with this:

```
string cou1 = Convert.ToString(cou.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this -

```
    var json = "{'territories':{'a10b4b1e-8400-4613-8c90-5d282de6a8a6':{'id':'a10b4b1e-8400-4613-8c90-5d282de6a8a6','name':'Connecticut','center':[41603071,-73087651],'timeZoneCode':'America/New_York','languageCode':null},'dc3d9d82-611e-41ba-a6f6-2c33ac5eebd1':{'id':'dc3d9d82-611e-41ba-a6f6-2c33ac5eebd1','name':'Orlando','center':[28538321,-81379242],'timeZoneCode':'America/New_York','languageCode':null}}}";
    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof (string));
    dt.Columns.Add("name", typeof (string));
    dt.Columns.Add("timeZoneCode", typeof (string));
    dt.Columns.Add("languageCode", typeof (string));
    dt.Rows.Add(obj.territories.A10b4b1e840046138c905d282de6a8a6.id,
               obj.territories.A10b4b1e840046138c905d282de6a8a6.name,
               obj.territories.A10b4b1e840046138c905d282de6a8a6.timeZoneCode,
               obj.territories.A10b4b1e840046138c905d282de6a8a6.languageCode);

    dt.Rows.Add(obj.territories.Dc3d9d82611e41baA6f62c33ac5eebd1.id,
               obj.territories.Dc3d9d82611e41baA6f62c33ac5eebd1.name,
               obj.territories.Dc3d9d82611e41baA6f62c33ac5eebd1.timeZoneCode,
               obj.territories.Dc3d9d82611e41baA6f62c33ac5eebd1.languageCode);
```

where -

```
public class A10b4b1e840046138c905d282de6a8a6
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<int> center { get; set; }
    public string timeZoneCode { get; set; }
    public object languageCode { get; set; }
}

public class Dc3d9d82611e41baA6f62c33ac5eebd1
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<int> center { get; set; }
    public string timeZoneCode { get; set; }
    public object languageCode { get; set; }
}
public class Territories
{
    [JsonProperty("a10b4b1e-8400-4613-8c90-5d282de6a8a6")]
    public A10b4b1e840046138c905d282de6a8a6 A10b4b1e840046138c905d282de6a8a6{get; set;}

    [JsonProperty("dc3d9d82-611e-41ba-a6f6-2c33ac5eebd1")]
    public Dc3d9d82611e41baA6f62c33ac5eebd1 Dc3d9d82611e41baA6f62c33ac5eebd1{get; set;}
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Territories territories{get; set;}
}
```

Comment: thanks for your code. The issue is that everytime when i get data the value change in `a10b4b1e-8400-4613-8c90-5d282de6a8a6' ,'dc3d9d82-611e-41ba-a6f6-2c33ac5eebd1` so i can't crate a class with that name like you create `public class A10b4b1e840046138c905d282de6a8a6` in the example